# Creating File & Directories not working properly

Tags: java, file, path

I am currently working on a method that will create files and directories. Bellow is the use case & problem explained.

1) When a user specifies a path e.g "/parent/sub folder/file.txt", the system should be able to create the directory along with the file.txt. (This one works)

2) When a user specifies a path e.g "/parent/sub-folder/" or "/parent/sub-folder", the system should be able to create all directories. (Does not work), Instead of it creating the "/sub-folder/" or /sub-folder" as a folder, it will create a file named "sub-folder".

Here is the code I have

```
Path path = Paths.get(rootDir+"test/hello/");
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
        if (!Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            Files.createFile(path);
        } else {
            Files.createDirectory(path);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use .mkdr() for the directory AND the file?

Comment: mkdir() does the same thing it, will still make what is supposed to be a directory to a file.

Comment: if you specifify path as `/parent/sub-folder` how JVM gonna recognize that you want to make a directory? I would create and file and this is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Then why is it not creating a folder when I try `/parent/sub-folder/` ?

Comment: @Andre `Files.isDirectory` only checks an existing folder, not one which is yet to be created. How do you distinguish between paths to files and paths to directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `createDirectories(Path)` instead of `createDirectory(path)`. As explained in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#create):

> To create a directory several levels deep when one or more of the
> parent directories might not yet exist, you can use the convenience
> method, createDirectories(Path, FileAttribute). As with the
> createDirectory(Path, FileAttribute) method, you can specify an
> optional set of initial file attributes. The following code snippet
> uses default attributes:
>
> Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("foo/bar/test"));
>
> The directories
> are created, as needed, from the top down. In the foo/bar/test
> example, if the foo directory does not exist, it is created. Next, the
> bar directory is created, if needed, and, finally, the test directory
> is created.
>
> It is possible for this method to fail after creating some, but not
> all, of the parent directories.

Comment: Yeah I was using it before, but the thing is, it will do the oposite problem of the one I already have. For example instead of creating "file.txt" into a file it will create it into a directory

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of which File API you are using. But find below the simplest code to create file along with folders using java.io package.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileTest fileTest = new FileTest();
        fileTest.createFile("C:"+File.separator+"folder"+File.separator+"file.txt");
    }

    public void createFile(String rootDir) {
        String filePath = rootDir;
        try {
            if(rootDir.contains(File.separator)){
                filePath = rootDir.substring(0, rootDir.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            }
            File file = new File(filePath);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println(file.mkdirs());
                file = new File(rootDir);
                System.out.println(file.createNewFile());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```